# Javascript/Postman compare json with nested objects ignoring order

Tags: javascript, json, compare, postman

I want to deep compare two json objects (Postman responses), which contain nested objects without taking into account the order. I need to write this comparison in a postman test.

```
json1 = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "toto": "toto",
        "array": [
            {
                "old": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "new": {
                    "value": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

json2 = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "toto": "toto",
        "array": [
            {
                "new": {
                    "value": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "old": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

json3 = {
    "b": {
        "toto": "toto",
        "array": [
            {
                "old": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "new": {
                    "value": 2,
                    "other": 4
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "a": 1
}
```

I expect `json1` and `json2` to show as equal (only order in nested array changes). `json1` and `json3` are different.
I have seen similar posts but none with the answer to this kind of object (sorry in advance if I missed one).

I tried several [lodash](https://lodash.com/) functions but failed to find a solution:

```
function customizer(baseValue, value) {
    
      if (Array.isArray(baseValue) && Array.isArray(value)) {
              return lodash.isEqual(lodash.sortBy(baseValue), lodash.sortBy(value))
            }
        
      }


console.log(lodash.isEqualWith(json1,json2,customizer)) -> false , I expect true
console.log(lodash.isEqual((lodash.sortBy(json1),lodash.sortBy(json2)))) -> same as above
console.log(lodash.xor(json1, json2).length) -> 0
console.log(lodash.xor(json1, json3).length) -> 0 , I expect different from 0 because of the "other"
```

I tried as well the `isMatch` (and `isMatchWith`) but it's too permissive. I don't want to allow the source to have more values than the other json (`isMatch` does only a partial deep comparison)

Can someone help please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that works for me :

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue, key, object, source) {
     
   if(Object.keys(object).length !== Object.keys(source).length){
     return false;
   }

  if(typeof objValue ==='object' && typeof srcValue === 'object'){
        if(Object.keys(objValue).length !== Object.keys(srcValue).length ){
                    return false;
        }
      }
      if (Array.isArray(objValue) && Array.isArray(srcValue)) {
           if(!(objValue.length === srcValue.length)){
              return false;
            }
        
      }
  }

console.log(lodash.isMatchWith(json1,json2,customizer))
```