# Compare trust policies while ignoring the order of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to compare 2 trust policies ignoring the order of the items in the Service array.

```
const compareTrustPolicy(RoleName)  => {

            const ExpectedTrustPolicy = {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                     {
                       "Effect": "Allow",
                       "Principal": {
                       "Service": [
                            "service1",
                            "service2"
                            ]
                        },
                      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                    }
                   ]
                  }
     return iam.getRole(RoleName).promise()
       .then((AssumeRolePolicyDocument) => {

         const obtainedPolicy =JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(AssumeRolePolicyDocument));
         assert.deepStrictEqual(trustPolicy, ExpectedPolicy, 'Not equal');


          }
};
```

At present, it only returns true when Service array is as below in trust policy obtained

```
"Service": [
       "service1",
       "service2"
]
```

And returns false when Service array is as below in trust policy obtained

```
"Service": [
       "service2",
       "service1"
]
```

Could someone help me modify the above code to result `TRUE` for any order of elements in Service array?

I read a [suggested post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63359123/javascript-postman-compare-json-with-nested-objects-ignoring-order), but it did not have any accepted answer or upvoted response.